# docker python exec_run() not working when running the container.exec_run("stress -cpu 1 &)

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I am trying to run this command with the docker python sdk but I am not sure I am passing the commands in properly. How would I run the command "stress --cpu 4 &" using the docker python sdk?

```py
m = container.exec_run("stress --cpu 4 &")
```

Comment: Where does `container` come from?  What error are you getting?  Are you launching this call from within a container, and if so, how are you starting it?  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?

Comment: when I run this, m = container.exec_run("stress --cpu 1 &"), I get this error ExecResult(exit_code=1, output=b'stress: FAIL: [325] (244) unrecognized option: &\n')

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it in one string

`m = container.exec_run("stress --cpu 4")`

there are some examples [here](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guides/multiplex.html)

if you want to run a command in background, don't use `&`, use `detach=True`

`m = container.exec_run("stress --cpu 4", detach=True)`

Comment: When I try to run the process in the background like this container.exec_run("stress --cpu 1 &"), it gives me this error, ExecResult(exit_code=1, output=b'stress: FAIL: [325] (244) unrecognized option: &\n')